# python function fails to return unless the last statement is slow

Tags: python, multithreading, debugging, python-multithreading

I'm working on a subclass of `threading.Thread` which allows its methods to be called and run in the thread represented by the object that they are called on as opposed to the usual behavior. I do this by using decorators on the target method that place the call to the method in a `collections.deque` and using the `run` method to process the deque.

the `run` method uses a `while not self.__stop:` statement and a `threading.Condition` object to wait for a call to be placed in the deque and then call `self.__process_calls`. The `else` part of the `while` loop makes a final call to `__process_calls`. if `self.__stop`, an exception is raised on any attempts to call one of the 'callable' methods from another thread.

The problem is that `__process_calls` fails to return unless the last statement is a `print` which I discovered during debugging. I've tried `a = 1` and an explicit `return` but neither work. with any `print` statement as the final statement of the function though, it returns and the thread doesn't hang. Any ideas what's going on?

EDIT: It was pointed out by David Zaslavsky that the print works because it takes a while
and I've confirmed that

The code's a little long but hopefully, my explanation above is clear enough to help understand it.

```
import threading
import collections    

class BrokenPromise(Exception): pass    
class CallableThreadError(Exception): pass    
class CallToNonRunningThreadError(CallableThreadError): pass   


class Promise(object):
    def __init__(self, deque, condition):
        self._condition = condition
        self._deque = deque

    def read(self, timeout=None):
        if not self._deque:
            with self._condition:
                if timeout:
                    self._condition.wait(timeout)
               else:
                    self._condition.wait()
        if self._deque:
            value = self._deque.popleft()
            del self._deque
            del self._condition
            return value
        else:
           raise BrokenPromise

    def ready(self):
        return bool(self._deque) 

class CallableThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs): 
        # _enqueued_calls is used to store tuples that encode a function call.
        # It is processed by the run method 
        self.__enqueued_calls = collections.deque() 
        # _enqueue_call_permission is for callers to signal that they have
        # placed something on the queue 
        self.__enqueue_call_permission = threading.Condition()
        self.__stop = False
        super(CallableThread, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs) 

    @staticmethod
    def blocking_method(f): 
        u"""A decorator function to implement a blocking method on a thread""" 
        # the returned function enqueues the decorated function and blocks
        # until the decorated function# is called and returns. It then returns
        # the value unmodified. The code in register runs in the calling thread
        # and the decorated method runs in thread that it is called on 
        f = CallableThread.nonblocking_method_with_promise(f)
        def register(self, *args, **kwargs):
            p = f(self, *args, **kwargs)
            return p.read()
        return register

    @staticmethod 
    def nonblocking_method_with_promise(f):
        u"""A decorator function to implement a non-blocking method on a
        thread
        """ 
        # the returned function enqueues the decorated function and returns a
        # Promise object.N The code in register runs in the calling thread 
        # and the decorated method runs in thread that it is called on. 
        def register(self, *args, **kwargs): 
            call_complete = threading.Condition() 
            response_deque = collections.deque()
            self.__push_call(f, args, kwargs, response_deque, call_complete)
            return Promise(response_deque, call_complete)
        return register

    @staticmethod
    def nonblocking_method(f):
        def register(self, *args, **kwargs):
            self.__push_call(f, args, kwargs)
        return register

    def run(self):        
        while not self.__stop:  # while we've not been killed 
            with self.__enqueue_call_permission:
                # get the condition so that we can wait on it if we need too. 
                if not self.__enqueued_calls: 
                    self.__enqueue_call_permission.wait() 
            self.__process_calls()
        else:
            # if we exit because self._run == False, finish processing
            # the pending calls if there are any
            self.__process_calls()

    def stop(self): 
        u""" Signal the thread to stop"""
        with self.__enqueue_call_permission:
           # we do this in case the run method is stuck waiting on an update
           self.__stop = True
           self.__enqueue_call_permission.notify()

    def __process_calls(self):
        print "processing calls"
        while self.__enqueued_calls:
            ((f,  args, kwargs),
            response_deque, call_complete) = self.__enqueued_calls.popleft()
            if call_complete:
                with call_complete:
                    response_deque.append(f(self, *args, **kwargs)) 
                    call_complete.notify()
            else:
                f(self, *args, **kwargs)
        # this is where you place the print statement if you want to see the
        # behavior        

    def __push_call(self, f, args, kwargs, response_deque=None,
                    call_complete=None):
        if self.__stop:
            raise CallToNonRunningThreadError(
                  "This thread is no longer accepting calls")
        with self.__enqueue_call_permission:
            self.__enqueued_calls.append(((f, args, kwargs),
                                           response_deque, call_complete))
            self.__enqueue_call_permission.notify()


#if __name__=='__main__':      i lost the indent on the following code in copying but
#it doesn't matter in this context
class TestThread(CallableThread): 
    u"""Increment a counter on each call and print the value""" 
    counter = 0

    @CallableThread.nonblocking_method_with_promise
    def increment(self): 
        self.counter += 1
        return self.counter

class LogThread(CallableThread):

    @CallableThread.nonblocking_method
    def log(self, message):
        print message

l = LogThread()
l.start()
l.log("logger started")
t = TestThread() 
t.start()
l.log("test thread started")
p = t.increment()
l.log("promise aquired")
v = p.read()
l.log("promise read")
l.log("{0} read from promise".format(v))
l.stop()
t.stop()
l.join()
t.join()
```

Comment: Without doing a full analysis, my first guess would be that `print` works because it takes a relatively long time, compared to something like `a=1`. You could try using something like `time.sleep(0.01)` instead and I think it should have the same effect, but without producing any output. Of course that's just a workaround. I can't guess why `__process_calls` would need that delay at the end to return properly.

Comment: @David. It works great. Of course, I'm still very curious about what's going on here. I'll try to boil the code down to something simpler

@bstpierre, you're right. I've edited the code to fix that. I can be a little spacy sometimes and I hadn't run that part of the code since I refactored it. I really do need to write some unit tests for this thing.

Comment: When you kill this, do you get a call stack? What is the calling location?

Comment: @bstpierrre, I do not get a callstack. when it hangs, `__process_calls` is called by the `else` clause of the `while..` statement in the `run` function. After that, it's all the standard call path from `threading.Thread.start()`

Comment: @bstpierre, to continue with my last comment, I tried pushing a dummy call onto the `deque` before the final call to `__process_calls` in the `else` clause. It makes no difference whether `__process_calls` is called with an empty deque or not. Also, it has no problem returning on all of the prior calls to it.

Comment: @aaronasterling - ok, this sounds like #3 in my answer below then. Look closely at the handling of the stop condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `__process_calls` is modifying `__enqueued_calls` without owning the lock. This may be creating a race condition.
2. **Edit**: deque may be "threadsafe" (ie not corrupted by thread accesses), but the checking of its state still should be locked.
3. The stop condition is also not safe.

Comments inline:

```
def run(self):        
    while not self.__stop:  # while we've not been killed 
        with self.__enqueue_call_permission:
            # get the condition so that we can wait on it if we need too. 
            ### should be checking __stop here, it could have been modified before
            ### you took the lock.
            if not self.__enqueued_calls: 
                self.__enqueue_call_permission.wait() 
        self.__process_calls()
    else:
        # if we exit because self._run == False, finish processing
        # the pending calls if there are any
        self.__process_calls()
```

Comment: I tried it and nope. the manual says that the `popleft` method on a `deque` is threadsafe. `__enqueue_call_permission` is really just a method for `__push_call` to signal to `run` that there is a new call on the `deque`. I should probably rename it.

Comment: It was 3. I'm still not sure how it works. My mental runthrough says that that mistake would result in `run` hanging on the call to `__enqueue_call_permission.wait()` but that's not at all the behavior that manifested. At any rate, it's fixed now.

Comment: I had the same thought. It looked wrong to me, but I couldn't figure out a failure scenario that matched your symptoms, but glad it's fixed.